# golang unmarshal (deserialize) variable type dictionary in struct

Tags: json, go, json-deserialization

This is a contrived example of my issue, so please ignore that this is solved by using a singular struct w/ json optional param.

Given:

```
    {
        "name": "alice",
        "address_dict": {
                            "home": { "address": "123 st" },
                            "work": { "address": "456 rd", "suite": "123"}
                        }
    }
```

```golang
type AddressIf interface{}

type AddressHome {
    Address string `json:"address"`
}

type AddressWork {
    Address string `json:"address"`
    Suite string `json:"suite"`
}

type Contact struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    AddressMap map[string]AddressIf `json:"address_map"`
}
```

```golang
func(self *Contact) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var objMap map[string]*json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &objMap
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var rawAddressMap map[string]*json.RawMessage
    err = json.Unmarshal(*objMap["address_map"], &rawAddressMap)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // how do we unmarshal everything else in the struct, and only override the handling of address map???
    // <failing code block is here - beg - just a tad, just a tad, just a tad - recursive>
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, self)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // <failing code block is here - end>

    if nil == self.AddressMap {
        self.AddressMap = make(map[string]AddressIf)
    }

    for key, value := range rawAddressMap {
        switch key {
            case "home":
                dst := &AddressHome{}
                err := json.Unmarshal(*value, dst)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                } else {
                    self.AddressMap[key] = dst
                }
            case "work":
                dst := &AddressWork{}
                err := json.Unmarshal(*value, dst)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                } else {
                    self.AddressMap[key] = dst
                }
            default:
                continue
        }
    }
}
```

I have just the `name` param in this sample bit of json, but let's assume I have more in my code. Is there a way to use the normal/default unmarshal for all the params, and then only manually take over for the `address_dict`, or is it the case that once I commit to implementing the interface for this object, I'm stuck manually deserializing each parameter?

I tried the following, and quickly realized why it didn't work.

```golang
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, self)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unmarshal remaining JSON after performing custom unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951510/unmarshal-remaining-json-after-performing-custom-unmarshalling)

Comment: It's a valid solution. And maybe the only one, but it does involve copying all the data from a different struct, back into the real owner. I'd accept it if nobody offers up a way to do it that doesn't involve an additional data type and individual copy of each non-custom element.

Comment: You could also just declare a named map type and have *it* implement the unmarshaler interface instead of the `Contact` type, unless you need some information from the contact type to properly unmarshal the map.

Comment: As an aside and just in case you're not aware, the use of receiver names like `self`, `this`, etc. is considered bad practice, or at the least it is *not* considered to be idiomatic. However you're free to use whatever names you like if those considered idiomatic are not to your liking.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/atMXsGtNkZZ

Comment: thanks for the info on what's idiomatic and not. I'm on a team that is transitioning a lot of python and c/c++ programmers used to embedded devices, so I specifically chose 'self' to make the code more friendly for teammates just glancing the code, to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the other answer would be to declare a named `map[string]AddressIf` type and have it implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface, then you do not have to do any of the temporary / anon type and conversion dance.

```
type AddressMap map[string]AddressIf

func (m *AddressMap) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if *m == nil {
        *m = make(AddressMap)
    }

    raw := make(map[string]json.RawMessage)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &raw); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for key, val := range raw {
        switch key {
        case "home":
            dst := new(AddressHome)
            if err := json.Unmarshal(val, dst); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            (*m)[key] = dst
        case "work":
            dst := new(AddressWork)
            if err := json.Unmarshal(val, dst); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            (*m)[key] = dst
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/o7zV8zu9g5X

Comment: It's such a weird concept to think of a map as a new type and implement an interface for it. Thanks for the late add!

Comment: @pyInTheSky in Go you can declare methods for **any named** type, including strings, integers, booleans, and even function types, which means even a function can implement an interface.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid copying Contact fields, use object embedding to shadow the fields that require special handling.

Use the factory pattern to eliminate code duplication across the address types.

See commentary for more info:

```
var addressFactories = map[string]func() AddressIf{
    "home": func() AddressIf { return &AddressHome{} },
    "work": func() AddressIf { return &AddressWork{} },
}

func (self *Contact) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {

    // Declare type with same base type as Contact. This
    // avoids recursion below because this type does not
    // have Contact's UnmarshalJSON method.
    type contactNoMethods Contact

    // Unmarshal to this value. The Contact.AddressMap
    // field is shadowed so we can handle unmarshal of
    // each value in the map.
    var data = struct {
        *contactNoMethods
        AddressMap map[string]json.RawMessage `json:"address_map"`
    }{
        // Note that all fields except AddressMap are unmarshaled
        // directly to Contact.
        (*contactNoMethods)(self),
        nil,
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Unmarshal each addresss...

    self.AddressMap = make(map[string]AddressIf, len(data.AddressMap))
    for k, raw := range data.AddressMap {
        factory := addressFactories[k]
        if factory == nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("unknown key %s", k)
        }
        address := factory()
        if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, address); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        self.AddressMap[k] = address
    }
    return nil
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WjFcPTsDFq0).

In a comment on the question, OP says that no additional types should be used.  This answer uses two additional types (`contactNoMethods` and the anonymous type for `data`).

Comment: way cool -- did not know that shadowing was a thing in go, and your no-copy solution w/ all but the special params was exactly what I was looking for -- thanks for the effort and the playground